# Docker exposing/publishing(NOT SIMPLE localhost->0.0.0.0 solution)

Tags: docker

When I run a server inside my docker with either "-p 8000:8000", "-p 8000", or "--expose 8000"  I can only connect to it, but it does not seem to be able to reply back. First of all it is not the classical localhost->0.0.0.0 problematic as I only use 0.0.0.0 as host. I tried with Flask, and "python -m SimpleHTTPServer" and none works. Another interesting(and probably related) problem is that I can't contact the outside from the Docker instance at all. E.g. if I run ping 8.8.8.8 I get unreachable host.

## edit

The simpelst way I can replicate the error is
Make a bash script called runner which have the following
`ping -c 2 8.8.8.8`

call

`sudo docker run -v ${PWD}:/app -w /app ubuntu ./runner`

in the same directory as the script.
This give the following output

`PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
92 bytes from c2fc631db1cd (172.17.0.49): Destination Host Unreachable
92 bytes from c2fc631db1cd (172.17.0.49): Destination Host Unreachable
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss`

Comment: Can you provide your system information (host OS, Docker version) and the steps for reproducing the issue (commands used and output)?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop as host and Ubuntu:latest I'm the instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. Apparently Docker can deadlock it's network interface in some weird way. This gives the illusion that you are not forwarding correctly, but in reality you can't communicate any direction if you use the network interface. The solution is to restart the Docker service(not the computer). This can be done in Ubuntu(possibly other Linux distributions) with `sudo service docker restart`.